# Syntax for setting paths to library and compiler in makefile

Tags: c, makefile, environment, gfortran, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile a program and I have to set the paths to the NETCDF inc and lib directories in the Makefile as well as set the gfortran and c compiler settings. The variables were already named as shown below, it just told me to edit the paths/options which I have tried to do. Here is what I have for my netcdf inc and lib, as well as the hdf5:

```
NETCDFINC = -I$(NETCDFF_INCDIR) -I$(NETCDFC_INCDIR)
NETCDFLIB = -Wl,-rpath=$(NETCDFF_LIBDIR) -L$(NETCDFF_LIBDIR) -Wl,-
rpath=$(NETCDFC_LIBDIR) -L$(NETCDFC_LIBDIR) -Wl,-rpath=$(HDF5_LIBDIR) -
L$(HDF5_LIBDIR) -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz
```

Note that the NETCDFLIB is on one line on my file, and the paths of the variables are correct, but the syntax may not be.

Next for the fortran and c compiler information I have the following:

```
FC   = gfortran -m64 -g -O0 -ffixed-line-length-132 -Wunused -Wuninitialized  
CC   = gcc 
CFLAGS = -m64 -c -g -I. -DLONG32 -DUNDERSCORE -DLITTLE -Wunused -
Wuninitialized
```

Finally, when I run the program I first get a bunch of warnings such as:

```
oban_namelist.f90:495.29:

 real              :: flt
                         1
Warning: Unused variable 'flt' declared at (1)
```

Followed by a bunch of undefined reference errors such as:

```
oban.o: In function `check':
/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/zpu-
group3/dhodges/DART/data/radar/opaws/oban.f90:1902: undefined reference to 
`__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'
```

The error shouldn't be in this oban.o function since I didn't write it. The only things I have edited in the program I listed above for the netcdf path and gfortran/c information and so I think the error lies there. This is my first question on here, so if I missed anything you need feel free to ask. What can I try?

Edit: By request, this is the entire makefile I am using. Also, I just type 'make' to compile it per the instructions in the README file.

```
# Makefile for creating the OPAWS analysis software
#
# Rev: 02/05/10 LJW
#      12/05/10 DCD
#      02/11/11 LJW
#

# netCDF4 libs - you need to fill in the blanks

NETCDFINC = -I$(NETCDFF_INCDIR) -I$(NETCDFC_INCDIR)
NETCDFLIB = -Wl,-rpath=$(NETCDFF_LIBDIR) -L$(NETCDFF_LIBDIR) -Wl,-rpath=$(NETCDFC_LIBDIR) -L$(NETCDFC_LIBDIR) -Wl,-rpath=$(HDF5_LIBDIR) -
L$(HDF5_LIBDIR) -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz

# Fortran and C compiler information - various configurations are setup, try and find one close

#=====>> Gfortran 
#  
FC   = gfortran -m64 -g -O0 -ffixed-line-length-132 -Wunused -Wuninitialized 
CC   = gcc
CFLAGS = -m64 -c -g -I. -DLONG32 -DUNDERSCORE -DLITTLE -Wunused -Wuninitialized

# Leave this stuff alone

EXEC = x.oban
EXECcs = x.clutter_stats
EXECmd = mosaic_2_dart

OBJS = DART.o oban_module.o dict_module.o oban_namelist.o derived_types.o util.o fileio.o read_dorade.o binio.o v5d.o 
OBJScs = DART.o dict_module.o oban_namelist.o derived_types.o fileio.o util.o read_dorade.o binio.o v5d.o
OBJSmd = DART.o dict_module.o oban_namelist.o derived_types.o fileio.o util.o read_dorade.o binio.o v5d.o

default: $(EXEC) $(EXECcs) $(EXECmd)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS) oban.o
    $(FC) $(OPT) -o $(EXEC) oban.o $(OBJS) $(NETCDFLIB)

$(EXECcs): $(OBJScs) clutter_stats.o
    $(FC) $(OPT) -o $(EXECcs) clutter_stats.o $(OBJScs) $(NETCDFLIB)

$(EXECmd): $(OBJSmd) mosaic_2_dart.o
    $(FC) $(OPT) -o $(EXECmd) mosaic_2_dart.o $(OBJSmd) $(NETCDFLIB)

clean:
    rm $(EXEC) oban.o $(OBJS) $(EXECcs) clutter_stats.o $(OBJScs) $(EXECmd) mosaic_2_dart.o $(OBJSmd) *.mod ncgen.input *.pyc sweep_file_list.txt

# Individual compilation instructions

oban.o: oban.f90 structures.inc opaws.inc DART.o
    $(FC) $(OPT) -c $(NETCDFINC) oban.f90

clutter_stats.o: clutter_stats.f90 opaws.inc
    $(FC) $(OPT) -c $(NETCDFINC) clutter_stats.f90

mosaic_2_dart.o: mosaic_2_dart.f90 opaws.inc
    $(FC) $(OPT) -c $(NETCDFINC) mosaic_2_dart.f90

oban_module.o: oban_module.f90 derived_types.o opaws.inc
    $(FC) $(OPT) -c oban_module.f90

read_dorade.o: read_dorade.c read_dorade.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c read_dorade.c

fileio.o: fileio.f90
    $(FC) $(OPT) $(NETCDFINC) -c fileio.f90

util.o: util.f opaws.inc structures.inc
    $(FC) $(OPT) -c util.f

DART.o: DART.f
    $(FC) $(OPT) -c DART.f

derived_types.o: derived_types.f90
    $(FC) $(OPT) -c derived_types.f90

oban_namelist.o: oban_namelist.f90 opaws.inc
    $(FC) $(OPT) -c oban_namelist.f90

dict_module.o: dict_module.f90
    $(FC) $(OPT) -c dict_module.f90

binio.o: binio.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) binio.c -o binio.o

v5d.o: v5d.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) v5d.c -o v5d.o
```

Comment: The `undefined reference to '__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror'` is a linker error. (the `f90` suggests it is fortran related) It's telling you it doesn't know what `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror` is. Possibly because you missed a header include (or a `-I/path/to/it`) or it just isn't declared before it is used. Post the entire Makefile along with a compile string that you can use to build your code successfully (if you have it). That will allow us to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: Do you still have a copy of what the original line that you changed to compare to? Without knowing how to compile what it is you are trying to compile, it makes answering very difficult. The `oban.o` library can't see a declaration for `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror`. Have you changed the order of the parts of either variable in the Makefile? It's looking for something that may need to be specified before `oban.o` is reached in your compile string.

Comment: I added the makefile above. Also the original code was as follows with blanks for me to edit:

    NETCDFINC = -I/   /    /netcdf4-64/include
    NETCDFLIB = -L/   /    /netcdf4-64/lib -lm -lnetcdf -L/   /    /hdf5/lib -
    lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz

and

    FC   = gfortran -m64 -g -O0 -Wl,-stack_size,10000000 -ffixed-line-
    length-132 -Wunused -Wuninitialized 
    CC   = gcc
    CFLAGS = -m64 -c -g -I. -DLONG32 -DUNDERSCORE -DLITTLE -
    Wunused -Wuninitialized

To compile I just type make, which is what the instructions say to do. I haven't changed the order they are called in.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, here are the instructions in the readme file as well if that helps to know: 
"Required software:

1.  Fortran compiler (gfortran/Intel)
2.  CC compiler (gcc is fine)
3.  netCDF3/4 installation with fortran (3 or 4)

BUILD instructions

1.  Edit the Makefile to put in your fortran and C compilers.  Two examples are provided.

2.  Setup proper links to the netCDF libs.  The fortran needs the include directory to use the netcdf module interface.

3.  Compile by typing "make".  Two executables are built:  x.oban and x.clutter_stats

Comment: From your error, it looks like you have a problem with "* 2. Setup proper links to the netCDF libs. The fortran needs the include directory to use the netcdf module interface.*" It doesn't know what `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_strerror` is. Are you sure it is installed with the proper links included so that `-I$(NETCDFF_INCDIR)` and `-L$(NETCDFF_LIBDIR)` resolve correctly. I don't compile a lot of fortran, are any `-lcdf...` libs required?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for your help, it got me going in the right direction. I edited the NETCDFLIB line as follows and it works: `NETCDFLIB = -Wl,-rpath=$(NETCDFF_LIBDIR) -L$(NETCDFF_LIBDIR) -Wl,-rpath=$(NETCDFC_LIBDIR) -L$(NETCDFC_LIBDIR) -lnetcdff -lnetcdf -lm -Wl,-rpath=$(HDF5_LIBDIR) -L$(HDF5_LIBDIR) -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz` Basically I just needed to add `-lnetcdff -lnetcdf -lm`, similar to your suggestion.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. That is what it looked like was missing, I just had no way to be absolutely sure. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by editing the NETCDFLIB line as follows:

```
 I edited the NETCDFLIB line as follows and it works: NETCDFLIB = -Wl,-
rpath=$(NETCDFF_LIBDIR) -L$(NETCDFF_LIBDIR) -Wl,-rpath=$(NETCDFC_LIBDIR) -
L$(NETCDFC_LIBDIR) -lnetcdff -lnetcdf -lm -Wl,-rpath=$(HDF5_LIBDIR) -
L$(HDF5_LIBDIR) -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz
```

Basically I just needed to add:

```
-lnetcdff -lnetcdf -lm
```

This allowed for the compiler to get access to the libraries it needed that were originally undefined.